# Store individual elements of a matrix into individual elements of a cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function in matlab returning a matrix of size `m x n`. I want to store each individual element of this matrix into individual elements of a cell with dimensions `m x n x p x 2`. Here `m,n,p` all are large numbers hence I need a solution without loops.

In other words I need a one line code to implenment the following loop:

```
    for k = 1:p
    out = func(parameters(k))  %out is mxn matrix
    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            cell{i,j,k,1} = out(i,j)
        end
    end
    end
```

Comment: What's with the fourth dimension?

Comment: Have you tried using `mat2cell`?

Comment: @Divakar my function outputs two matrices of same size and I have to store both of them in the same cell. Hence the fourth dimension

Comment: @Dan I will have to use `mat2cell` as `cell = mat2cell(a,[1,1,1,1,1....m times] , [1,1,1....ntimes])` and it is difficult  as I mentioned that m and n are large numbers. Also, `mat2cell` will return me a cell with dimensions `m x n` while I need a cell with dimensions `m x n x p x 2 `

Comment: @nishantsny you can use `mat2cell(a, ones(1,m), ones(1,n))` (though you probably need to add a `ones(1,p)` as well)

Comment: @Dan Still the second problem(which is more important) which I mentioned in my earlier comment remains unsolved. I am repeating the problem here : `mat2cell` will return me a cell with dimensions `m x n` while I need a cell with dimensions `m x n x p x 2` .

Comment: @nishantsny, can't you just concatenate the two outputs using `cat(4, output1, output2)`? alternatively, the `mat2cell` approach works fine you just need to pre-allocate and then assign something like this: `C{m,n,p,2} = []; C(:,:,:,1) = mat2cell(a, ones(...),...); C(:,:,:,2) = mat2cell(b,....)`

Comment: what about `num2cell`? and where does the 2 in the forth dimension come from?

Comment: @Dan your first method worked , thanks . your second method doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue the `x 2` comes from in your `m x n x p x 2` output, but you could try something like:

```
p = 10; n = 15; m = 20;

result = arrayfun(@(x) num2cell( func(x) ), 1:p, 'uni',0);
output = reshape([result{:}],n,m,p);
```

or:

```
result = arrayfun(@(x) func(x), 1:p,'uni',0);
output = num2cell(reshape([result{:}],n,m,p));
```

with output being a `15 x 20 x 10 x 1` cell. Where every cell element contains an "array" with one numerical value.

If you insist, the quirky one-liner:

```
output = num2cell(reshape(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) func(x),1:p,'uni',0)), n,m,p) );
```

Comment: it basically specifies the inputs of `arrayfun` - for every element of `1:p` which `arrayfun` sees as `x` the function `func(x)` is executed.